# Can ping hostname on local network, but need to use FQDN over VPN?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, internal-dns

When I `ping DC1` on a local network using only the hostname, I receive an expected response. However, if I ping a remote DC (`DC5` for example) over site-to-site IPsec VPN, I receive the following error:

`Ping request could not find host DC5. Please check the name and try again.`

If I try to ping the FQDN `dc5.mydomain.com`, I receive a response.

Why is it that hostnames are working locally, but not over the VPN tunnel?

Comment: It sounds to me like the VPN client doesn't have a DNS suffix. If you run nslookup in interactive mode with debug and query for DC1 while connected to the VPN what does the query look like?

Comment: Server:  dc1.mydomain.com
Address:  172.10.10.100

------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = SERVFAIL
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        dc5, type = A, class = IN

------------

Comment: ------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 3, rcode = SERVFAIL
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        dc5, type = AAAA, class = IN

------------
*** dc1.mydomain.com can't find dc5: Server failed

Comment: Its a DNS Suffix problem. Add dns suffix mydomain.com in your computer properties.